# boot camp windows 7 install disk hangs

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp

I am trying to install windows 7 using boot camp and I was able to set up the partition successfully using the boot camp assistant, but when I try to boot off of the windows 7 install cd, it just hangs at a black screen with a white cursor in the upper left corner.

I've successfully booted off of this cd before though, so I don't think this is the problem.  Is there something else that could be going on here?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What system/mac do you have?

Comment: Are there any external drives plugged in? I find that my Boot Camp booting suffers large delays when I have other bootable external drives plugged in, even after I get past the OS selector. This may be affecting you during the bootup of your install disk.